# origin/master commits are leaks into the history of another remote branch slave/master

Tags: git, version-control

I wrote a simple bash script which is initialize 2 bare repos (`king` and `slave`). This script you can copy to terminal and just execute to reproduce issue.

Within `king` repo I've added remote branch to `slave` repo.

**The problem** is when I try to push new commit into the `slave` repo with cmd `git push slave master` some strange push fail occurs... Like I did not fetch new changes from remote and this changes prevents my try to push new commit... 
But this is not so...

ygyerts@ygyerts-Aspire-V3-771:~/repos/wd/king$ git push slave master

> To /home/ygyerts/repos/bare/slave.git  ! [rejected]        master ->
>   master (non-fast-forward) error: failed to push some refs to
>   '/home/ygyerts/repos/bare/slave.git' hint: Updates were rejected
>   because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote hint: counterpart.
>   Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes hint: (e.g.
>   'git pull ...') before pushing again. hint: See the 'Note about
>   fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

I can push new changes just with `-f` flag, which adds this `"init commit in king"` from `king/origin/master` to history of `slave/master`. **Which is absolutely unacceptable!**

```
tput reset

#======================================
# Clean workspace
#======================================
rm -rf ~/repos/bare
rm -rf ~/repos/wd

#======================================
# Create required folders
#======================================
mkdir -p ~/repos/bare
mkdir -p ~/repos/wd

#======================================
# Create Bare Repo KING
#======================================
cd ~/repos/bare
git init --bare king.git

#======================================
# Create Bare Repo SLAVE
#======================================
cd ~/repos/bare
git init --bare slave.git

#======================================
# Clone and Initialize KING repository
#======================================
cd ~/repos/wd
git clone ~/repos/bare/king.git
cd ./king
echo "KING" > king.txt
git add . && git commit -m "init commit in king"
git push origin master

#======================================
# Clone and Initialize SLAVE repository
#======================================
cd ~/repos/wd
git clone ~/repos/bare/slave.git
cd ./slave
echo "SLAVE" > slave.txt
git add . && git commit -m "init commit in slave"
git push origin master

#======================================
# Add remotes to KING repo
#======================================
cd ~/repos/wd/king
git remote add slave ~/repos/bare/slave.git
git fetch slave
git branch -a
```

> - master
>
>   remotes/origin/master
>
>   remotes/slave/master

```
#======================================
# Set upstream branches to within KING repo
#======================================
cd ~/repos/wd/king

git checkout slave/master
git checkout -b slave_master
git branch --set-upstream-to=slave/master slave_master

#======================================
# Add changes to slave/master through the king repo
#======================================
cd ~/repos/wd/king
git branch -vv
```

> master       fbdc59a [origin/master] init commit in king
>
> - slave_master 6370a7d [slave/master] init commit in slave

```
git checkout slave_master
echo "king > slave/master" > king_to_slave.txt
git add . && git commit -m "add changes from king repo"
git push slave master
```

> To /home/ygyerts/repos/bare/slave.git  ! [rejected]        master ->
>   **master (non-fast-forward) error: failed to push some refs to**
>   '/home/ygyerts/repos/bare/slave.git' hint: Updates were rejected
>   because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote hint: counterpart.
>   Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes hint: (e.g.
>   **'git pull ...'**) before pushing again. hint: See the 'Note about
>   fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

`git pull` doesn't help!

Comment: I don't understand this statement: "I can push new changes just with `-f` flag, which adds this `"init commit" from king/origin/master` to history of `slave/master`. **Which is absolutely unacceptable!**" Do you understand Git's branch model? What is your expected result?

Comment: when I try to do simple push, it is fails. But when I try to push with force option activated, this push cmd pushes not only required changes (only one new commit), it also pushes init commit from absolutely another branch `origin/master`.

Comment: I just expecting push of newly created commit

Comment: The main goal is to work with `origin/master` and `slave/master` remotes from `king` cloned repository. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found and error in my script. But I didn't understand the problem.

Error was in push cmd `git push slave master`

Correct cmd is `git push slave slave_master:master`

But I still not understand why `git push -f slave master` cmd takes all commits from `origin master` and try put them into history of `slave master`